# Expected expression before char with variadic function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm getting the error expression "expected expression before char"

```
char *set_buffer(char *buf, int num_str, ...) { 
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num_str); 
    for (int i = 0, offset = 0; i < num_str; ++i) {
         char *str = va_args(args, char *); // error here
         offset += snprintf(buf+offset, strlen(str), str); 
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

Anybody have any idea why?c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro is `va_arg` not `va_args`

```
char *str = va_arg(args, char *)
```

Comment: @GeorgeNewton happens to everyone from time to time :)